# Using python pandas to parse CSV with date in format Year, Day, Hour, Min, Sec

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

I have several CSV files with the format:

```
Year,Day,Hour,Min,Sec.,P1'S1
 2003,  1, 0, 0,12.22, 0.541
 2003,  1, 1, 0,20.69, 0.708
 2003,  1, 2, 0, 4.95, 0.520
 2003,  1, 3, 0,13.42, 0.539
...
```

(where *day*, is the *day of the year*) and I'm trying to read them using the **pandas** library (seems a fantastic lib so far).

There is a built-in function to read CSV in pandas, and even better, that function supposedly checks the columns for a date type. and automatically uses that as an index (which would be exactly perfect for what I'm doing).

The thing is, I cannot get it to work with date data in this format.

I tried:

```
data = pd.read_csv("csvFile.csv", index_col=[0, 1],  , index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] parse_dates=True)
```

but **it only gets the year correctly**:

```
In [36]: data.index
Out[36]: 
MultiIndex
[(<Timestamp: 2003-09-04 00:00:00>, 1, 0, 0, 12.22)
 (<Timestamp: 2003-09-04 00:00:00>, 1, 1, 0, 20.69)
 (<Timestamp: 2003-09-04 00:00:00>, 1, 2, 0, 4.95) ...,
 (<Timestamp: 2003-09-04 00:00:00>, 365, 21, 0, 3.77)
 (<Timestamp: 2003-09-04 00:00:00>, 365, 22, 0, 14.6)
 (<Timestamp: 2003-09-04 00:00:00>, 365, 23, 0, 13.36)]
```

From the documentation, I see that you can specify the **"date_parser" attribute in the read_csv function of pandas**. But the documentation doesn't show how and I'm not being able to figure it out.
Anyone with experience in the subject that can give a hand.

Cheers,
Bruno

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to parse a multi-column date, you need to tell pandas which columns should be combined into a single date, so you need to say `parse_dates=['Year','Day','Hour','Min','Sec']`

You also need to define your own parser that takes a element from each column you specified in `parse_dates`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta

In [3]: from cStringIO import StringIO

In [4]: data = """\
Year,Day,Hour,Min,Sec.,P1'S1
 2003,  1, 0, 0,12.22, 0.541
 2003,  1, 1, 0,20.69, 0.708
 2003,  1, 2, 0, 4.95, 0.520
 2003,  1, 3, 0,13.42, 0.539
"""

In [5]: def parse(yr, doy, hr, min, sec):
    yr, doy, hr, min = [int(x) for x in [yr, doy, hr, min]]
    sec = float(sec)
    mu_sec = int((sec - int(sec)) * 1e6)
    sec = int(sec)
    dt = datetime(yr - 1, 12, 31)
    delta = timedelta(days=doy, hours=hr, minutes=min, seconds=sec,
                      microseconds=mu_sec)
    return dt + delta
   ...: 

In [6]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates={'datetime':      
           ['Year','Day','Hour','Min','Sec.']}, 
           date_parser=parse, index_col='datetime')
Out[6]: 
                            P1'S1
datetime                         
2003-01-01 00:00:12.220000  0.541
2003-01-01 01:00:20.690000  0.708
2003-01-01 02:00:04.950000  0.520
2003-01-01 03:00:13.419999  0.539
```

Comment: I checked, and the problem is that the file has a space before the "Year" header (just like the year values below it). It works perfectly if I put a space in read_csv before the 'Year' to become ' Year'. Very picky, but works.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Using `pandas.to_datetime()`

```py
import pandas as pd

def parser(year, yday, h, m, s):
    return pd.to_datetime(year + '-' + yday + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s,
                          format='%Y-%j %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',
         parse_dates={'datetime': ['Year','Day','Hour','Min','Sec.']}, 
         date_parser=parser,
         index_col='datetime')
```